# Can a rejected manuscript be submitted to another Elsevier journal?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, paper-submission, elsevier

- Can one submit a rejected manuscript from one Elsevier journal to another relevant/similar Elsevier journal after apply the given feedback from the reviewers?
- Is there any minimum wait time?
- Is it recommended to do so?
- Would the other Elsevier journal know the status about the previous submission to the first journal? Will this have any impact on the decision of the second Elsevier journal?

Comment: What were the problems with the paper raised by the referee?

Comment: The paper was submitted to a very high Impact Factor journals from Elsevier. They decided that the quality is not at their journal standard.

Comment: This could mean a couple of different things, including "the paper was good, but not good enough for us" and "the paper was bad". If the reviewer comments go into the former direction, resubmit straight away. If they go into the latter direction, you are still allowed to resubmit, but it's not the best idea to do so.

Comment: in IOP journals, if they feel that the paper is OK, but not good enough for that specific journal, they automatically redirect you to another of their journals, often using the same reviewers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[EDIT: I just submitted a review, and there was a little box ticked, saying]

> In the event that this manuscript is rejected by this journal and
>   transferred to another E******* journal I agree that this reviewer
>   report, my name and email address may be transferred alongside it.

[This corresponds to the second point below]

So, unless you are banned by a society and forbidden to publish in their journals for some reason (e.g. plagiarism), there are fences between two different journal submission systems. And no rule known to me.

However, two aspects require caution:

- close journals, especially with the same publisher, may have the same editors, area editors, etc. It is interesting to check the editor list and check for an overlap
- since reviewers are hard to find, I suspect that a publisher may have a database of all its parts reviewers (whatever the journal). So with a similar paper, the same keywords, you might as well end up with the same reviewer. Who might have mixed feelings about reviewing "the same paper" twice.

From what I understand from your question, your paper might have been mildly reviewed, possibility checked by an editor, who made the decision himself. So the second point might be as less concern.

Answer (score 21):

In general, when a paper is rejected, you can resubmit it to another journal as soon as you feel you are ready.  There is no minimum waiting time, and it doesn't matter whether both journals have the same publisher or not.

As far as I know, publishers don't generally share information about submissions between journals.  (However, it could happen that the second journal would require you to tell them about any previous places the paper has been submitted.)

In theory some publishers might have special rules, but I've never heard of this.

Comment: There's one (sort of funny) exception, the [P vs NP policy of JACM](http://jacm.acm.org/pnp-policy.cfm). There is a certain problem in Computer Science (Is P = NP? See https://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm for some explanations) that is open for a long time, and claims that it was solved are frequent. If you submit a paper to JACM claiming that you solved it, and a reviewer finds a flaw, you have to wait 24 months before resubmitting!

Comment: (And it could also happen that the journal is going to ask exactly the same reviewer to review your document: if you only made light modifications to your document, without addressing the reviewers concerns, his/her answer might be exactly the same!)

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon the reason for the rejection.

If your science is fundamentally flawed and the paper in written particularly poorly, then I imagine that resubmission is not advised (to any journal).

Alternatively, if the paper is high quality but is rejected for addressing the practical aspects of a topic (whereas the journal in question deals only with theoretical aspects) then it may be perfectly reasonable to resubmit to a more appropriate location without modification.

I cannot answer your further questions about data sharing, though I believe the other answers begin to address this.